# rviz: how to change reference frame for camera view

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, 2d-mapping, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In old version of rviz, there was an attribute 'target frame' in Global options, it sets the reference frame for camera view. For example, if my robot is moving, the camera view will also move along the robot. Will always show me the map from robot perspective. In latest version (1.12.16 (kinetic)) I could not find this. How can I set target frame ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301129/rviz:-how-to-change-reference-frame-for-camera-view/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2018-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I'm not mistaken that setting migrated to the view plugins. You should be able to find it as one of the items listed under the active view plugin listed in the *Views* panel.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0